# Why do more transitions imply more bandwidth consumed?

Tags: can, bandwidth

First thing first, I found a [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/272658/why-does-more-bandwidth-guarantee-high-bit-rate) very similar to this one, so if the answer is already in that one please write it down and I will look there.

While studying CAN bus, I read the distinction between *Non Return to Zero* (NRZ) and *Return to Zero* (RZ) ... I would like to trivially ask why RZ, having more transitions, takes up more bandwidth. What is the concept behind this.

Thanks!

Comment: *why RZ, having more transitions,...* <--RZ doesn't have more transitions.

Comment: @Andyaka Not being English perhaps I am confusing the term "transitions" ... the fact is that every time it has to return to zero

Comment: That's still not correct. NRZ has more transitions by a mile usually.

Comment: @Andyaka It is by general definition exactly opposite to what you say. Perhaps you should state what's your definition for NRZ and RZ.

Comment: @Justme for instance, Manchester encoding implements NRZ and it produces far more transitions per bit.

Comment: @Andyaka The raw data is NRZ and it's not NRZ any more if you apply Manchester line coding or RZ to raw data.

Comment: I was of the belief that NRZ meant the data never returned to a null state (unlike a UART transmission). It seems I'm wrong, but so must be a few others who taught me that definition. Never too old to learn. Thanks @Justme

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because for an NRZ signal the fastest signal you can have on wire is an  alternating ...101010... pattern which are the bits themselves. For a 1 Mbps data rate the maximum frequency of the square wave is 0.5 MHz.

With RZ line code, for each bit, you have two transitions, which means for 1 Mbps data rate you have 1 MHz square wave.

And, 1 MHz square wave takes double the bandwidth than 0.5 MHz square wave.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and concise answer! I kindly ask you (since I am a beginner in the subject) if you can explain a little better why "for a 1 Mbps data rate the maximum frequency of the square wave is 0.5 MHz". I thought about it for a while and I interpreted it that way, but 
probably wrong: 1Mbps is 10^6 bits every second, so 1/10^6=1MHz the frequency. These bits can be 1 or 0 ... 50% chance, so the freq of "1" is 0.5MHz and the freq of "0" is always 0.5MHz ??

Comment: @KaleM No, nothing to do with chance or probability. If you forcibly define the worst possible NRZ signal, it can have at most one transition for each bit, so that's why a 1 Mbit signal with transtition for each bit generates a 500 kHz square wave as shortert high level is 1us and shortest low level is 1us and repeating that is a square wave with 2us period.

Comment: @KaleM Because for the NRZ signal a full cycle of a square wave is `10` = 2 bits. So at 1 Mbps that's 1,000,000/2 = 500,000 full cycles per second.

Comment: A clean square wave at 0.5MHz will have strong harmonics at 1.5MHz, 2.5Mhz, 3.5Mhz, etc.  If instead of outputting 101010, one outputs 1001001 at 1Mhz, etc. one would end up harmonics at 0.667Mhz, 1.333Mhz, 2.667Mhz, 3.333Mhz, etc.

Answer (score 4):

When you send data on a medium, on top of the data itself, you need to also add some sync information.

Imagine you have a very simple encoding where 1 is a high signal and 0 is a low signal.

If you want to send data which consists of 100 ones, 10 zeroes and 100 more ones, you would end up with a signal that is high for 100 samples, low for 10, and high for 100.

But how can you be sure that the receiver has the same timing as the sender? Maybe its clock is a bit faster than the sender and it will think it has received 110 ones, 11 zeroes and 110 more ones. Or on the contrary it may be a bit slower and it will think the signal is 90 ones, 9 zeroes, and 90 more ones.

That’s why encodings also carry some form of sync information. In async protocols, you usually have start and stop bits, and a small enough number of bits between them that it’s very unlikely sync will be lost between them.

In sync protocols, you don’t have that: you have a long stream of bits (often hundreds, thousands, or even a never-ending stream), and you need to maintain sync.

Some interfaces will simply send the clock on a separate line. That’s the case of I2C for instance: there’s a clock (SCL) and a data line (SDA). The receiver watches the clock, and samples the data line whenever the clock goes from low to high. Everybody stays in sync.

Other interfaces just can’t afford two separate lines for clock and data. So the clock will be somehow embedded in the signal, which carries both data and sync.

In NRZ, you only send data. There’s one state for 1, another state for 0, and while there may be another state for “no data”, it is not used during a transmission. If you send a signal at 100 Mbits/s, and that signal is a succession of ones and zeroes in alternance, then a full cycle (a period) is the duration of two bits. In other words, the same signal repeats again and again every two bits. This gives us a frequency of 50 MHz, and since this is the maximum frequency the signal could have, that’s its bandwidth.

But that signal does not carry any clock or sync information. If you actually have only an alternance of ones and zeroes, as describe above, then it’s easy for the receiver to resync on each transition (from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0), but if there are long series of ones or long series or zeroes, sync could be lost, and the receiver could have counted more or less bits that were sent.

That’s why other encoding schemes try to somehow include sync information in the signal, in addition to the data. In RZ, you have three states, often positive, negative and 0. To send a one, you send a positive signal, then 0. To send a zero, you send a negative signal, then 0.

This allows the receiver to keep sync: whatever the data sent, each bit will start with a transition (from 0 to positive or from zero to negative), and end with another one (back to 0).

But that means that if you have a long stream of ones to send, then the signal you will send will include, for each bit, a transition from 0 to positive and one from positive to negative.

This means that in this case, the signal will repeat for every bit, and the bandwidth in Hz will be the same value as the bit rate in bits/s. So our earlier 100 Mbits/s stream now needs a bandwidth of 100 MHz.

Other forms of encodings like Manchester have the same types of properties. While they only use two states, they will like RZ have up to two transitions per bit. One is for the data, the other is for the clock.

Other schemes are more subtle: instead of sending a clock with every single bit, they send a stream which is mostly one signal per bit, but have rules preventing long strings of ones (or zeroes), so they have lower bandwidth requirements.

Comment: UART uses asynchronous start stop framing which it adds to data, but that framed data is still sent as NRZ over the wire, so it does not add anything beyond the bit rate.

Comment: Another variation is MFM, which is a little bit like Manchester encoding, with a phase transition in the middle of a bit time representing a "1", but with the phase transition that would occur between bit times omitted except when the bits before and after are both "0".  This increases the maximum time without a phrase transition from 2 to 4, but increases the minimum time from 1 to 2, thus meaning that the maximum transition rate equals the bit rate (as with NRZ) but without need for inter-byte framing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer! I don't know if I can "accept" two answers, because both yours and @Justme helped me a lot. In any case, thank you both.